# why Java script click event doesn't fired in the first page loading?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Java script click event doesn't fired in the first page loading after i refreshed the page it works fine the below is my code

**page 1:**

```
<h:form id="sellsForm">
    <ui:include src="../mypages/page2.xhtml" />
    <h:panelGroup id="sellsPanel" layout="block" styleClass="my_panel">
        <h:outputText id="sellitem" value="#{bean.selecteInfo}" styleClass="high" rendered="#{bean.selecteInfo == null ? false : true}"/>       
    </h:panelGroup>     
</h:form>
```

**../mypages/page2.xhtml**

```
<div class="menu_element">
    <a4j:commandLink styleClass="service_icon"
        action="#{bean.setSelecteditem('Service')}" immediate="true" render="sellsPanel">
        <h:outputText value="#{msgs['menu.service']}" />
        <br/>           
    </a4j:commandLink>
</div>
```

**js**

```
$('div."menu_element').click(function() {
    debugger;
    var siblingDivs = $(this).parent().children();
    siblingDivs.each(function() {
        if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
            $(this).removeClass("selected");
        }
    });
    $(this).addClass("selected");
});
```

Comment: No reason to tag this as 'java', java and javascript are not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**you can use**

```
$(document).on('click','div."menu_element',function() {
        debugger;
        var siblingDivs = $(this).parent().children();
        siblingDivs.each(function() {
            if($(this).hasClass("selected")) {
                $(this).removeClass("selected");
            }
        });
        $(this).addClass("selected");
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

javascript function should be in body onload `onload="myFunction()"` or in jquery `$( document ).ready(function() { alert(); });`